# wget does not always retrive data

Tags: dns, wget

I've got a problem with wget, but I do not know where real issue is:
my wget (normally POST data, seems to be correct, tried with GET also the output is the same) does not allways retrive the result (body) from the opposite server. Maybe now I can say, from 10 tries 4-6 will fail (this is also not acceptable).

I searched the internet, and found maybe a DNS problem exist on the side of client and
`/etc/resolv.conf`
should also be edited.
Okay, than I've installed for this purpose resolvconf and set up 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for DNS (as mentioned on the page).

What an improvement. Now from 10 tries, only 1 fails, that's better than before, but I'm expecting 0 fails, due, that the line between the two pc-s is good enough and has no interruptions in the monitored period.

I've started custom logging and saw, that the request is going out but it never reaches the server.

I've also checked my apache logs (on server side to make it sure), and also aknowledge, that in fact, the get command does not arrive in this case.

I've also played with the `--timeout` increasing it, but this has also no effect on the statistics (`--no-check-certificate` because I thought is has something to do with the SSL cert).

My wget command is now: `wget -qO - --timeout 1 --no-check-certificate --post-data "foo=bar" https://mywebsite.php`

So I'm confused, I don not think cURL will get better statistics. My firewall even does not blocking it, no rule for that, the request is not very frequently, only about only once per 30-120 secs Apache modsecurity will also not affect this.

Any Idea? Better DNS settings?

Comment: (A) You have checked that the failing wget attempt is not even reaching the webserver , hence it is not Issue with webserver or wget. DNS is improved but still you have some other Issue in the network. (B) You should try wget or curl with the IP instead of the hostname. If that gives 100% success , then Issue is DNS. If that also gives 10% failure , then Issue is elsewhere in the network where some Packets are getting dropped Intermittently. (C) You can check that by using ping or traceroute continuously. (D) You might try using wget with some other client PC or some other webserver.

Comment: maybe this was also an idea, but if you use SSL than you can't just use the IP for a request... but with the ping it is a good idea... now running it.

Comment: Pass  `-v`  to `wget`  like e.g. `wget -v http://refpersys.org/refpersys-snapshot.tar.bz2` or use the [curl](https://curl.se/) command.

Comment: Does the server/some firewall on front of it have rate limiting? There are a lot of unknown variables...ask them. Also do you pause between tries?

Comment: You didn't tell us how you determined that "that the request is going out but it never reaches the server". The nature of TCP is that it would be impossible for the data to go out without completing a TCP handshake (and a TLS handlshake for https). So the corresponding events are detectable at the remote end.

Comment: Hi Guys, most of you does not read carefully. why should I use the -v parameter for wget? Curl will also not bring the propper statistics, or? What arguments do you have for it? This was also a question.
"Does the server/some firewall on front of it have rate limiting" like I said, no there isn't any. please read carefully.
How to determine? Maybe you use (custom) logs for this case. Handshake is a second step, the first step is the dns resolution, if this does not happen, no second step will happen (and say hello to each other and so on...)
For everybody: its about DNS resolving problems.